# 'Int' object not callable with simple equation

Tags: python, int

Im using the IDLE interface to python 2.7, and am getting the 'int object not callable' error and trying to figure out exactly why I get it. Im still relatively new to Python. I went to check [Beginner Errors: Python.org](http://wiki.python.org/moin/BeginnerErrorsWithPythonProgramming) and wasnt able to figure out my problem.

I simply put in 6/5(6+7) and get the error. I can get rid of the parenthesis and it works fine. Could someone explain why it does this, so that maybe I can avoid this issue later?

Comment: What do you want that to mean? `5(6+7)` isn't a valid python expression; did you mean `5 * (6+7)`?

Comment: Note: in Python 2.7, `6/5` will give you `1` because the division of two integers is truncating.  Would floating point numbers (`1.2`) work for you or do you need fractions?

Comment: I was just doing expressions to learn little things here and there. I tried 5(6+7) in the IDLE, Wobble, and same error. I would have to use 5*(6+7) to get the answer Im looking for. Just curious as to any specific reason why it works the way it does.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You cannot multiply numbers by simply putting them next to each other or surrounding with parethenses, you need to explicitly use `*`:

```
6/5*(6+7)
```

Comment: Hmm, Alrighty. Thanks for the answer. Would you be able to explain why it must be explicitly used in this way as opposed to the initial way I was trying?

Comment: That's a tricky question.  Why did you expect it to work the way you were trying?  Each symbol (+ - / * and others) is an operator that runs a piece of program code, and they are meant to look and behave like mathematical operators, but a line of Python code is not a mathematical expression in the same format that you'd write it on the chalkboard even if very simple mathematical expressions end up looking alike.  More specifically, allowing implicit multiplication by putting variables or numbers next to each other may turn typos like leaving an operator out into subtle errors.

Comment: on top of what @AndrewGorcester explained , when you do 5(4) , python reads this code as function call , normal functions are used like function(args) , for the interpreter you are trying to call the  function 5 with the arg 4 ! that's why you get the not callable error , 5 is a int value not a callable object ie: a function or a class

Comment: Good point -- in Python functions are objects, and ints are objects, and when you type a number in without any variable name that's called a "literal" but it's still an object.  There's no syntax separating objects from one another, so any object can potentially be callable.

Comment: That makes perfect sense. I didnt think of it that way. Thank you both very much for the responses. Now I know.

Answer (score 2):

To multiply `6/5` by `(6+7)`, use `*`:

```
6/5*(6+7)
```